# mongodb cross collection update object_id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I am trying to update cross collection update, for example

I have two collections, One collection name is **users** and another collection name is **user_businesses**. Below is the sample data of both the collections.

user collection data:

```
 {

_id: ObjectId("64a6b0f5af3af7f59a05ba33"),

id: 134,

display_id: 'PRM-SRL-000001348',

client_emp_code: '',

entity_code: '',

user_type: 'candidate',

role: '',

user_account_type: '',

business_id: 104,

parent_id: 94,
```

user_businesses collection data:

```
    {

_id: ObjectId("64a6b0f5a488ab4bc843d331"),

id: 31,

business_id: 196,

contact_person: '',

phone_code: 1,

phone_iso: 'us',
```

I want to update **users** collection **_id: ObjectId("64a6b0f5af3af7f59a05ba33")** to **user_businesses** collection **business_id** column (act as a **foreign key**) based on where condition **users.id=user_businesses.business_id**.

I have used below code, the code executed successfully, But values are not updated. Please someone correct me the code if i am wrong.

```
    db.users.find().forEach(function(userDoc) {

var matchingBusinessDoc = db.user_businesses.findOne({ business_id: userDoc.id });

if (matchingBusinessDoc) {

db.user_businesses.updateOne(

{ business_id: userDoc.id },

{ $set: { business_id: userDoc._id: ObjectId } }

);

}

});
```

Comment: Can you provide the code your using?

Comment: db.users.find().forEach(function(userDoc) {

var matchingBusinessDoc = db.user_businesses.findOne({ business_id: userDoc.id });

if (matchingBusinessDoc) {

db.user_businesses.updateOne(

{ business_id: userDoc.id },

{ $set: { business_id: userDoc._id: ObjectId } }

);

}

});

Comment: Give my answer a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: Let me check and update you.

Comment: @QueryKiller Data are updated, thanks for fix the issue.

Comment: You're welcome! Syntax errors are the worst, I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below should update the `business_id` field in the `user_businesses` collection with the corresponding `_id` from the `users` collection based on the condition `users.id = user_businesses.business_id`.

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(userDoc) {
  var matchingBusinessDoc = db.user_businesses.findOne({ business_id: userDoc.id });
  if (matchingBusinessDoc) {
    db.user_businesses.updateOne(
      { business_id: userDoc.id },
      { $set: { business_id: userDoc._id } }
    );
  }
});
```